# Question predicated on the OP being a well known contemporary person

Tags: discussion

I have flagged [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/67098/going-to-law-school-at-age-70-want-to-become-a-professor-of-criminal-justice#comment162619_67098) and voted it for closure.  It purports to be about an older incarcerated felon asking tips for how to get into law school.  My issue with the question is that the OP identifies himself as [O.J. Simpson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O._J._Simpson) and all the specific details of the question are clearly modelled on Mr. Simpson's situation, including the felony record and likely parole date.  I hope we can agree that with overwhelming probability the OP is not actually O.J. Simpson.

I voted for closure as "off-topic because not asked in good faith," but the majority of votes to close the question were as an exact duplicate.  (Because of the way the SE platform works, I am listed as someone who voted to close the question as a duplicate.  This is just not true, and the blithely counterfactual nature of it is a bit annoying.)  There are currently two votes to reopen.

I feel that any question on this site in which a user impersonates a real person and includes key details about that person's life as part of the premise of the question is clearly not being asked in good faith and is inappropriate here.  I feel that the question should certainly stay closed and not for the reason that it is an exact duplicate (it isn't).  Perhaps the question should even be deleted.

The user who gave the currently accepted answer has a comment indicating he understands the impersonation but I wonder how many of the other voting users have fully grasped what is going on.  Is it possible that this question is viewed as appropriate by experienced users of the site who are fully apprised?  I find that a bit surprising, but please discuss.

Comment: Wait - that wasn't O.J.? :)

Comment: I can't see the deleted question. But would the question be ok, had it been written in third person (as a hypothetical) rather than in first person?

Answer (score 23):

It is a troll. I have deleted the question. While there may be an interesting question in there, I would prefer a non troll to ask it than trying to heavily edit the question to make it fit.

If it happens again, you can flag it as offensive to feed the troll detection algorithm. See [this META.SE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-work) for the difference between spam and offensive flags.

Comment: If the guy was geniune then he would have used his real name because he said that he wanted to be honest .I was going to answer his question but I smelt a rat .